# Is there a familiar phrase for spending too much time on something?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

We all know that "a stitch in time saves nine" and "an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure", but sometimes the opposite is true.  A stitch *before* its time is a waste of time and thread.  If you wash your car right before you go off-roading, you're basically throwing soap away.

I've heard the phrase "you ain't gonna need it" in software development circles related to this sort of situation, but I'm looking for a more mainstream idiom, proverb, or cliché, if there is one.

The situation would be someone who is expending a lot of time or resources on something that might in some situations be a good investment, or even seems like a good investment at the time, but ultimately it doesn't pay off.

Answer (score 3):

In software developer circles *gold plating* refers to putting effort into a feature or product when it's no longer adding value. Wikipedia has a [short article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_%28software_engineering%29) on this.

Comment: Preaching to the choir. 
Burning daylight. 
Arguing with a wooden Indian.
Whistling up the wind.
Hollering down a well.

...a lot of them. 

Best wishes.

Answer (score 3):

One might say “Don't overcomplicate this”, or  “Don't overthink this”, where *[overcomplicate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overcomplicate)* is a verb meaning  “To make something excessively complicated” and *[overthink](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overthink#Verb)* is a verb meaning  “To think or analyze too much”.  Wiktionary gives the following example:

> Don't overthink the problem. It's not that difficult.

---

The phrase “A stitch before its time” in the question perhaps suggests admonishments about *premature optimization*.  Quoting from Knuth:

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; **premature optimization is the root of all evil** (or at least most of it) in programming. – 1974 Turing Award Lecture, Communications of the ACM 17 (12), (December 1974), p. 671

— As seen in [wikiquotes](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29), but with emphasis added.

---

It also suggests a phrase (which was mentioned, but deleted, by moonstar2001):  *Putting the cart before the horse*.  [Thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+the+cart+before+the+horse) offers the following definition and example for this phrase:

> to do things in the wrong order. *Deciding what to wear before you've even been invited to the party is rather **putting the cart before the horse**, isn't it?*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart_before_the_horse) says, inter alia, that *putting the cart before the horse* means doing things the wrong way round or with the wrong emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

"Gilding the Lily" is close - trying to improve on something already beautiful.  It doesn't really address the time wasting aspect.

"Don't make a mountain out of a molehill" is a phrase for overcomplication or exaggerating is key.

"Wearing both Belt and Suspenders" is one that fits the "being too cautious"

Comment: IMO "belt and suspenders" describes the usual good practice for telecom providers: when you pick up the phone in an emergency you *always* want to hear a dial tone; so for example having *two* emergency generators at the network exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[**Wild goose chase**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/wild-goose-chase.html)

Someone going on a wild goose chase spends a lot of time on a futile pursuit.

Wiktionary also suggests [**merry dance**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merry_dance).

> - A useless waste of time resulting from a deception.
>
> The children led us on a *merry dance* with their stories of strangers and shadows in the night.

Answer (score 1):

"overcooking" is popular in government circles.  If you search the right forums for the coarser variety of "polishing" metaphor you'll probably find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

People can get caught up in "Analysis Paralysis" - i.e., spending an unreasonable amount of time and effort trying to perfect their approach/solution, often before taking *any* material action, such that (from an outsider's perspective) they are too far into the area of diminishing returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***dillydally*** is the word you are looking for.

> [dillydally](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dillydally)- means to waste time by delaying or loitering; to move
>   or act slowly

Example:

> Stop *dillydallying*! You need to submit those reports in the
>   afternoon.
>   Sean, you're *dillydallying*. Focus on your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

**Time suck**

From Dictionary.com:

> something that takes up too much of one's time

It is certainly informal, but could be used as:

> After two weeks and little progress, it was apparent that the project was becoming a time suck.